# openByUrl из списка другой таблицы

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function superfunc() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheet3.getRange("A"+i).getValue());
var Dinam = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2');
for (h=2;h<=4;h++){
ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheet3.getRange("A"+i).getValue());
Dinam = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2');     
for (g=2;g<=sheet1.getRange(1, 7).getValue();g++) {
svod.getRange("A"+i).setValue(Dinam.getRange("A"+g).getValue());
svod.getRange("B"+i).setValue(Dinam.getRange("B"+g).getValue());
svod.getRange("C"+i).setValue(Dinam.getRange("C"+g).getValue());
svod.getRange("D"+i).setValue(Dinam.getRange("D"+g).getValue());    
i++;}}}
```

подскажите пож-ста, где ошибка? 
Скрипт должен из файлов, ссылки на которые пользователь указал на отдельном листе, копировать данные (первые четыре столбца) во вкладку СВОД, без пробелов и пропусков.

в файле на 3 странице будут вставлять ссылки на гугл таблицы (столбец А, с ячейки А2 и ниже)

Comment: А зачем Вы полностью поменяли вопрос? Лучше бы новый создали.

Comment: переменная "sheet3" у вас не инициализирована

Comment: переменные i, h, g тоже нигде не указаны как переменные (var)

Comment: var i=2;
  var g=2;
  var h=2;
  var rs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var svod = rs.getSheetByName('Свод');
  var sheet1 = rs.getSheetByName('Лист1');
  var sheet2 = rs.getSheetByName('Лист2');
  var sheet3 = rs.getSheetByName ('Лист3');

Comment: не влезло в вопрос... можете помочь?))

Comment: Сделайте нормальный код, внесите все изменения, укажите, что именно не работает и в каком месте выдает ошибку

Comment: Сергей, если скажете свою почту, могу отправить ссылку на файл и небольшое вознаграждение за помощь, просто файл нужен для работы, а времени самому сделать качественно  -  нету....(

Comment: Боюсь, данная площадка нужна именно для вопросов-ответов. То что хотите Вы - это фриланс. Обратитесь на биржу фриланса (куча в инете по поиску)

Answer (score 1):

[getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) возвращает данные в виде:

> Object[][] — a two-dimensional array of values

А [openByUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openByUrl(String)) принимает параметром

> String - The URL for the spreadsheet.

То есть вы вместо строки передаете методу двумерный массив. Если вам нужна 1 ссылка, а не их массив - то воспользуйтесь методами:
[getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) или [getDisplayValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue())

Comment: спасибО!!!54545

Comment: Если ответ Вас устраивает - не забудьте его принять - нажав на галочку

Comment: весь код не работает(

Comment: @Max, ТЗ решить надо или домашку?